# MS Excel Find text and replace with Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, replace, hyperlink

I am looking to replace multiple occurrences of text with a hyperlink that is masked by the same text.

Scenario:
We are moving to Google Classroom and thinking ahead to September. I can export pupils timetables in bulk to excel as HTML files (let's call this file timetables).
I have a separate file with a list of all class names and the links for the Google Classrooms (lets call this one classes). I have copied these values into 'Sheet1' of the timetable file for the code below.

If I can use the classes list to search for all occurrences of the classes in the timetables then replace them with the hyperlink to the Google Classroom but I want it to appear as the classname.

**Timetable file**
This is one timetable but the file continues the same pattern for different pupils.
[image]

**Classlist file**
Imagine there were all classes listed and links were valid.
[image]

I have been trying this code that I found but cannot get a working hyperlink in the "replace" element.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook from a table
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

'Create variable to point to your table
  Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2")

'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
  
'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
          sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
      Next sht
  Next x

End Sub
```

[Example timetable file](https://gofile.io/?c=olI3yT)

Comment: Does it just insert the text without a hyperlink?

Comment: Yes it just inserts the link as text. I would like it to insert the clickable link but I want to appear as the text of the class name. I was trying the vba Hyperlink.add but wouldn't work for me.

Comment: What was the hyperlink code you were using, as that appears to be central problem? Have you tried recording a macro of inserting the link? In fact you probably don't need the find and replace, couldn't you just add the link?

Comment: `Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a5"), _ 
 Address:="https://example.microsoft.com", _ 
 ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site", _ 
 TextToDisplay:="Microsoft"`

This was the format of the code. The problem was occurring in Anchor a I was not sure what to use.
The address I was using was myArray(rplcList, x) and the text to display was myArray(fndList, x).
I'm not sure I follow you about just adding the link. The file contains around 246 timetables with over 100 different classes.

Comment: `Worksheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add ...`

Comment: The anchor is the cell in which the link is placed. If you have a table with items in one column and links in the second column you just need to loop through the first, find the item and insert a link using the value in column 2.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to what to put in the Anchor. The code is looking at all the cells matching cells in the timetable sheet that match the cells in the classlist. What do I put in anchor to single out the selected cell without hyperlinking every cell in the timetable sheet?

Comment: Is your desired output that every cell in your first pic containing "11C1/Fp" has the same contents but is a hyperlink to the same address (google in your example)? And ditto for other values?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: I will mock up a simple example which hopefully you can adapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It appears that the link requires the full address including "https".

I mocked up a two-column table and a few values to test.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, t As ListObject, rFind As Range, s As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set t = .ListObjects("Table1")
    For Each r In t.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange 'loop through first column of table
        Set rFind = .Range("A:C").Find(What:=r.Value, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'look for value
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            s = rFind.Address 'store address of first cell
            Do
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rFind, Address:=r.Offset(, 1).Value, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:=r.Offset(, 1).Text, TextToDisplay:=r.Value 'add hyperlink
                Set rFind = .Range("A:C").FindNext(rFind) 'look for next instance
            Loop While rFind.Address <> s 'keep going until back to first case
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Links table**

[image]

Comment: I was unable to get this to work for my layout but it would work if I set it up the way you have here with test data. Thank you for your time. I have included a sample file of my timetables in the OP.

Comment: What exactly is the problem.

Comment: There is no error appearing. However I tried a couple of this this morning with a fresh set of eyes. The issue appears to be in the timetable data. It wouldn't work even if I copied the data to a new excel file. If I manually type the same text over the text that was there it works. It looks like even though the text looks the same it is not.

Comment: You could try `Lookat:=xlpart` but might fall down depending on how unique are your entries.

Comment: I found the issue. I knew I had trailing spaces in the exported data so I allowed for that in the classlist data. The exported data was using chr(160) for space and obviously I was using space bar which would be chr(32).

Comment: I added 
`Cells.Replace What:="?", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False`
after the start of the With Statement to remove the spaces. I copied the particular space so it would recognise it. Now your code works flawlessly.
Now just to automate this for the exported data.